# How does one calculate the principial component stresses in an ellipsoidal tank due to head pressure?

Tags: structural-engineering, fluid-mechanics, modeling

I have parameterized the following common bulkhead tank, which has cylindrical walls (easy enough) and ellipsoidal bulkheads. The upper tank is full of a fluid of density 800 kg/m^3 and the lower is full of a fluid of density 1141 kg/m^3. Dimensions are in m, internal tank pressure (in green) is in 10s of kPa. I assume the shared bulkhead is perfectly rigid & no pressure is transmitted between tanks.

I am trying to calculate the principal stress components in the ellipsoidal bulkheads so that I can obtain full-body radial and longitudinal stress profiles. I can't find any information on how to do this, or (better yet) a generalized approach to determining surface stresses from pressure in non-spherical or non-cylindrical situations. I'm not an engineer by training & I have trouble knowing where to start with this. Help?

[image]

Comment: Here's a sample for the non-circular cyclinder case. https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a319059.pdf . The bulkhead calcs have a similar DTIC document which has been posted here at least twice by me.

Comment: Here's the bulhead document - https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/615090.pdf

Comment: holy moly this looks fantastic